# Returning variable outside backbone function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to return profile.toJSON() to an object so as to use it outside the above code. I am not understanding exactly how backbone function works, so i declare a global variable obj and trying to parse data with  obj = profile.toJSON(). When i  use console.log(obj) it displays successfully my data. When I put console outside the above code it returns underfined.

```
var obj; 
var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend(
{       
    el: "#profiles",
    template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
    render: function(eventName) 
    {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(profile)
        {
            var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());  
            obj = profile.toJSON();
            $(this.el).html(profileTemplate);
        }, this);

    return this;
    }           
});
```

Comment: Where you want to use it?

Comment: I want to parse in another javascript file varible obj.

Comment: That's because your outside `console.log` is called before the rendering had a chance to take place.

Comment: If you are using Backbone, just get the collection in the view you require.

Comment: Except from the HTML display i want to make some calculations with the data. So I want to return an object in another js file for calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking it by the wrong end. Precreate your model and pass it to a view. Don't try to extract something from the view rendering code, it's not meant to be used this way.

```
var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var ProfileCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Profile
});

var ProfileListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    // Everything render does is rendering
    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            this.$el.append(
                this.template(model.toJSON);
            );
        }, this);
    }
    ...
});

// Your profile instance is defined outside the view, making 
// it de facto available to outside code
var profile = new Profile({
    name: 'Fere Res',
    rep: 48
});

// The profile we just created gets added to a collection
var profiles = new ProfileCollection([profile]);

// We create the profile list view and pass it the collection
var view = new ProfileListView({collection: profiles});

// When we render the view, the render() code defined above is called.
// You can easily see that all the params/variables it uses are in place
view.render();

// Rendering is done, let's check our model is still available
console.log(profile.toJSON()); // :)
```

Comment: You're right, I copied some code without thinking too much about it. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks. This reminded me of collection.each I tend to forget.

Comment: Thanks, finally i got it!!

Answer (score 0):

I ve got this code which actually fetch data from json file:

```
$(function() {

    var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
                tstamp: "",
                map:"",
                tagsCloud:"",
                sentiment: "",
                usersCloud: "",
                timeline: "",
                highlights: "",
                signals: ""
        },

        initialize: function() {

        }

    });

    var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

                    model: Profile,
                    url: 'data.json'
    });   

    var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#profiles",
        template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
        render: function(eventName) {

        _.each(this.model.models, function(profile){
        var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());

        //obj = profile.toJSON();
        //console.log(obj.tstamp);

        $(this.el).html(profileTemplate);
        }, this);

            return this;

        }


    });

        var profiles = new ProfileList();    
        var profilesView = new ProfileView({model: profiles});

        setInterval(function() {
                profiles.fetch({reset: true});
                }, 400); // Time in milliseconds
                profiles.bind('reset', function () {
                profilesView.render();
        }); 
       });
```

I tried to add profiles to a new   collection:

```
      var profiles1 = new ProfileList([profiles]);
      var view = new ProfileView({collection: profiles1});
      view.render();
      console.log(profile.toJSON());
```

I ve got console message: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined